# Whats the best way to generate an SPSS .SAV file from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, spss

I need to provide some export functionality in my web application for SPSS. I've looked at some very old solutions for generating .SAV files for SPSS but they're either incomplete or don't work at all. If anyone has come acrsoss something, please let me know.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm also searching a way to create files for SPSS

Answer (score 1):

I might not be fully versed in .net, but I do know that there are examples of interfacing with VBA and SAX basic, which I think are all closely related, right?

Check out the Data Management book put out by SPSS (older versions) and the Scripting Guide for SPSS.  [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/support/techsupport.html) is a link to an older version but it may get you started.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .Net library that interop with spss.dll. I'm using it and it runs very well, looks very stable.

http://spss.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps.